# Does the word Effortless imply a negative or a positive comment?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I watched a TV show where a group of dancers were performing a number. After that, the host interviewed one of the audience and he was told that the Group A's performance was *effortless* and gave a low rating to that group.  However one of judges questioned the audience why did he gave a low score if the performance was effortless.

Comment: The use of *effortless* in this context is incorrect. Could have been 'did not put in sufficient effort (to deserve)'. 'Effortless' *per se* has no negative connotations.

Comment: The presenter **used the word wrong**.  The presenter meant "they made no effort". The word "effortless" is indeed **the highest form of praise**. You might say something like, Shakespeare or Da Vinci were effortless geniuses, or, "they made it look effortless".

Comment: Most dictionary definitions show _effortless_ to mean _requiring no effort; easy_. A low score for an _easy_ performance seems right.

Comment: Was whoever said that a native speaker? I am not a  native speaker, and although I find the usage of this word in that context rather uncommon, it would not immediately appear wrong to me. I would interpret it as "it did not require them any effort to do this performance, thus I rated them low because all the others really put effort into it".

Comment: @Frank: Totally wrong. You use "effortless" to indicate that something required no effort and was easy _for the person who did it_, while typically requiring lots of effort from other people. A piano performance _should_ be effortless; if the audience notices the effort, it distracts from the music and the player should play something easier.

Comment: @gnasher There are two definitions, one is _so piss easy it's not worthy of praise_ the other is _doing something difficult but making it look piss easy_. Music - chopsticks is effortless and hardly worthy of praise, if you can do Mozarts Conc.15 b flat major effortlessly then it's worthy of praise. That was effortless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually, if I hear someone's performance described as having been *effortless,* I assume it was so well executed that every aspect of it looked as though it flowed naturally -- in other words, it was *done without apparent effort.*

In the case you describe, *effortless* seems to have been used with a different sense in mind. Specifically, whoever applied the term when describing the dancers' performance was implying that they had *made no effort* -- in other words, they had not worked very hard on the standard of their performance.

This usage is distinctly different to the normal sense in which the word is applied.

Comment: Erik, i wouldn't say "usually" in the first para - that's simply the meaning of the word.  The presenter simply misspoke.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Please feel free to add any further pedantic comments you may have.

Comment: LOL fair enough Erik. But, I hope you can see what I'm getting at: I'm on a bit of a rant against "overly-explanatory" answers on this site.  (EXAMPLE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105695 ) The amazingly simple, full, totally complete answer here is "(a) the presenter completely used the word wrong, such as when somenoe thinks penultimate means really good" and (b) for the meaning, check a dictionary".  I feel your answer (for example) muddies the waters. The presenter (as presented here) did not "have a different sense in mind..", the presenter is an idiot, or, simply misspoke.

Comment: So, I'm sorry.  I'm sorry you got caught up in this whole horror.  I love your icon, though  :O

Comment: (Surely as a professional proofreader, if you saw someone make that mistake you'd just X it out and put in the correct word, right?  Maybe I'm wrong here.)

Comment: @JoeBlow - Sorry for my rather intemperate response to your remark. (I guess you caught me when I was in the mood to be irritated.) The icon is taken from a website devoted to taxidermic faux pas (actually, I notice that user [holnet](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/71963/holnet) has also created an icon from one such specimen -- in his/her case, it was supposed to be a lion). And yes, you're right -- when I'm correcting people's texts, I have no compunction about deleting/correcting their mistakes; if an unresolvable ambiguity or other query arises, I insert a comment in the document

Comment: You certainly don't have to apologise, I'm the one who should apologise. Fascinating; I didn't realise it was "real" image! BTW for taxidermy, consider 46 rue du Bac, Paris 7e

Comment: I think this is the strongest answer to the OP's question. On the surface, _effortless_ seems to imply "absence of effort," but the focus of the term (as most English speakers use it) is on the appearance of (not) making an effort. A superb athlete can make some remarkable feat look effortless in part because so much effort has gone into training. The judge here meant something like "low-effort." Interestingly, both _effortful_ and _labored_ often show up in contexts where they are intended as criticisms—not of effort per se, but of effort that is somehow unskilled, of trying too hard.

Comment: +1 and +1 to Sven too. The meaning might not be the common sense, but it's still valid.

Answer (score 14):

If I say I could carry out a task effortlessly that means that it will be easy for me to do it nicely without putting in much efforts. 
That implies I am naturally good at it.

It is used in a positive manner.
The first judge used it incorrectly.

Comment: You'll soon have 100,000 points with answers that good!

Comment: When you say effortless you imply (it looks) but if you specifically say it WAS effortless there is an argument that technically that is a correct but uncommon usage. In reality for that meaning someone would use a word like lazy.

Comment: You are right , it would depends on the tone too in some situations but generally it is related to the world natural : not requiring effort. If you are to use it to define someone's performance, it would always be positive eg : it was an effortless performance , will be a praise.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good question because "effortless," in my opinion, is another example of a contronym: it can mean both **showing no effort** (I.E. *seemingly* "doggin' it"), as well as **needing no effort** (I.E., performed with ease). The former connotes a lack of commitment, while the latter implies talent that exceeds that normally required to achieve success.

I think the first definition is widely misinterpreted as one *who is actually doggin' it*, when in reality it only *appears* that way (which leads to the second, and I believe more accurate, definition).

Comment: It doesn't mean "showing no effort". It can be wrongly used by someone who wants to say "showing no effort" but uses the wrong term instead.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like that audience member was confused with the common usage of 'effortless'. There's a distinct difference between saying that the performance *was* effortless and saying that the performance *appeared* effortless.

It is far more common in my experience to hear how the actions of some skilled professional *appeared* effortless. That is, that they are so good at what they do that, to the layman, it appears as if they make no effort at all and yet achieve amazing feats (such as graceful dancing).

It's much rarer to hear the word 'effortless' used to mean that someone has performed so poorly that they seemed to have *made no effort*.

Since 'effortless' is almost exclusively used to denote expertise, I'd say the audience members' use of the word was incorrect in this context.

Comment: With answers that good, all you need is to change to an actual nickname, and you'll soon have 100,000 fun points!

Comment: Ah! I hadn't noticed. How ironic that Joe Blow tells me I need an _actual_ nickname. Thanks. Fun points, here I come!

Comment: Dude! "joe blow" is very much a nickname!!  Being so old, I'm very scared of revealing my identity on the internet so I always use a non de plume.  TBC you could use either a nickname, or, just your real name.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary gives the following explanations and examples for "effortless": Requiring no physical or mental exertion. _I went up the steps in two effortless bounds. Each skill is practiced to the point that it becomes effortless." Achieved with admirable ease: "Her effortless sense of style".

Anyone using the word to indicate something negative just uses it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think one has to distinguish between the **meaning** of a word (as defined in a dictionary) and the way in which it is used (commonly or in a particular case).

Given that it is perfectly possible to use the word "effortless" in a way that doesn't imply any kind of value judgment on the speaker's part, it is clear that there are no positive or negative implications analytically attached to its meaning.

When you use a word in a particular context, however, its meaning will also depend on the linguistic context and the particular situation in which it is used. In this sense, although the first member of the audience didn't use the word "effortless" correctly, we still understand what he meant, because otherwise we wouldn't even be able to judge whether he used the word correctly or not.